# How to exit if a on of shells failed?

Tags: bash, shell-script, solaris

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle DB with a Perl script to execute some queries on solaris OS, and I have saved each one of them like:

```
create table t1 ..
update t1 ..
insert into t1 ..
```

The main point is that they must run sequentially and if one of them fails, the script should exit. How can I write a shell script that exits if one part of it fails?

I have tried many times with `set -e`, but it doesn't work well on Solaris. Finally, I found something like this but I'm getting the same problem, it keeps failing each time:

```
if ! nohup /data/scripts/drop_table.pl   >> /info/saved/LOG/`date +\%Y\%m\%d`_result.log   2>&1;
then echo "dropping error!!" >&2;
exit 1;
fi

if ! nohup /data/scripts/update_table.pl   >> /info/saved/LOG/`date +\%Y\%m\%d`_result.log   2>&1;
then echo "updating error!!" >&2;
exit 1;
fi

if ! nohup /data/scripts/insert_table.pl   >> /info/saved/LOG/`date +\%Y\%m\%d`_result.log   2>&1;
then echo "insertion error!!" >&2;
exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: Why not put everything in one `sql` file and use `BEGIN...COMMIT` ?

Comment: Does your `perl` script exit with a non-0 status if the SQL command fails? Also, if you already have perl scripts, why aren't you doing the whole thing in Perl?

Comment: im still newbew with perl and unix , my script only execute query and then end the connection

Comment: `drop_table.pl` creates a table?

Comment: sorry i i will replace it now